# In what data type is the VirusTotal API returning the data in?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, frontend, backend, web-development-server

My current code structure looks like this:

React frontend server set where user uploads a file. Then that file is sent to my backend server which is based on Node and express.js. Next, the file is sent to this url: "https://www.virustotal.com/api/v3/files" alongside my personal API key and it is supposed to return with some sort of data.

Firstly I'm unsure of what data is supposed to be returned back to me and secondly, I believe the file is not being sent properly from my backend to virustotal's url.

These are the errors Im running into when I click on the submit file button through my frontend:

```
Popup.js:17     POST http://localhost:5000/upload 500 (Internal Server Error)
Popup.handleSearchClick @ Popup.js:17
callCallback @ react-dom.development.js:4164
invokeGuardedCallbackDev @ react-dom.development.js:4213
invokeGuardedCallback @ react-dom.development.js:4277
invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError @ react-dom.development.js:4291
executeDispatch @ react-dom.development.js:9041
processDispatchQueueItemsInOrder @ react-dom.development.js:9073
processDispatchQueue @ react-dom.development.js:9086
dispatchEventsForPlugins @ react-dom.development.js:9097
(anonymous) @ react-dom.development.js:9288
batchedUpdates$1 @ react-dom.development.js:26140
batchedUpdates @ react-dom.development.js:3991
dispatchEventForPluginEventSystem @ react-dom.development.js:9287
dispatchEventWithEnableCapturePhaseSelectiveHydrationWithoutDiscreteEventReplay @ react-dom.development.js:6465
dispatchEvent @ react-dom.development.js:6457
dispatchDiscreteEvent @ react-dom.development.js:6430

Popup.js:23 {error: 'Error processing file'}error: "Error processing file"[[Prototype]]: Object


Popup.js:34 Error sending file to backend: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'last_analysis_results')
    at Popup.js:26:1
```

Here is my code for the Frontend

```
import React from "react";

class Popup extends React.Component {
  handleSearchClick = () => {
    const fileInput = document.getElementById("fileInput");
    const file = fileInput.files[0];

    if (!file) {
      alert("Please select a file.");
      return;
    }

    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("file", file);

    // Send the file to the backend
    fetch("http://localhost:5000/upload", {
      method: "POST",
      body: formData,
    })
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((data) => {
      console.log(data);
    
      // Access different attributes of the data to display or process as needed
      const scanResults = data.attributes.last_analysis_results;
      for (const engine in scanResults) {
        if (scanResults.hasOwnProperty(engine)) {
          console.log(`${engine}: ${scanResults[engine].category}`);
        }
      }
    })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error("Error sending file to backend:", error);
      });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>VT Hash Search</h2>
        <input type="file" id="fileInput" />
        <button onClick={this.handleSearchClick}>Search</button>

        {/* Add the result section to display the hash value */}
        <div className="result-section" id="resultSection">
          <h3>Hash Value:</h3>
          <div className="result" id="hashResult"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Popup;
```

Here is my code for the backend

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const cors = require("cors");
const multer = require("multer");
const axios = require("axios");

app.use(cors());

const PORT = 5000;

app.use(express.json());

// Configure multer to handle file uploads
const upload = multer();

// Route for receiving the file from frontend and forwarding it to VirusTotal
app.post("/upload", upload.single("file"), async (req, res) => {
  const fileContent = req.file.buffer; // Use req.file.buffer to access the file content

  const apiKey = "MY_API_KEY";
  const searchUrl = "https://www.virustotal.com/api/v3/files";

  const formData = new FormData();
  formData.append("file", fileContent);

  try {
    // Send the file to VirusTotal API
    const response = await axios.post(searchUrl, formData, {
      headers: {
        "x-apikey": apiKey,
        "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data", // Set the Content-Type header for the file
      },
    });

    // Process the data received from VirusTotal as needed
    const data = response.data;
    res.json({ data: data });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error sending file to VirusTotal:", error.message);
    res.status(500).json({ error: "Error processing file" });
  }
});

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server started on port ${PORT}`);
});
```

I've tried playing around with the code and making a few changes here and there in terms of what data is to be expected to return when the file is sent and changing the formData constant i've set up in both files. Have also made sure all the additional dependencies such as axios, express and multer have been set up in the back end alongside with CORS to avoid any blockages or access issues in my browser but still no luck.

I expect my code to send a file from my backend server to the virustotal url and return results back to me.